# AsyncSnapshot is always null in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to show list from `GraphQl` and my query is working and getting data in future but `AsyncSnapshot` showing always null.

I debugged the code and every value is coming without any exception.

This is my `FutureBuilder` to load list

```
Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<InventoryListData>(
              future: getInventory(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<InventoryListData> snapshot) {
                Log.e('VECHILE hasData', 'LOG-------:::${snapshot}');
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return buildList(snapshot);
                } else if(snapshot.hasError)  {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                    snapshot.error.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'regular',
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  )));
                }
                return progressBar();
              },
            ),
```

This is my method to getdata in future.

```
 Future<InventoryListData> getInventory() async {
    GraphQLClient _client =
        graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery(GraphQlConstant.INVENTORY);
    await _client
        .mutate(MutationOptions(
      document: gql(
        addMutation.getInventory(idToken),
      ),
    )).then((result) {
      if (!result.hasException) {
        try {
          var response = InventoryListData.fromJson(result.data);
          Log.e('', 'LOG-------:::${response.vehicles.length}');
          return response;
        } catch (e) {
          Log.e('EXCEPTION', 'LOG-------:::${e}');
        }
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: '${result.exception}',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            fontSize: 18.0);
      }
    });
  }
```

My response on Insomnia

[image]

My fetch data method  calling inside `initState` instead of direct calling `getInventory()` method inside `FutureBuilder`.

```
  void _fetchSession() async {
    try {
      CognitoAuthSession res = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
          options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));
      idToken = res.userPoolTokens.idToken;
      NetworkCheck.checkConnection(context).then((onValue) {
        if (onValue) {
          //request = apiProvider.inventoryListService(idToken,WebConstant.INVENTORY_LIST);
          //request = apiProvider.inventoryListService(idToken,WebConstant.INVENTORY_LIST);
          request=getInventory();
          setState(() {
            request;
          });
        }
      });
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

No error is showing

> AsyncSnapshot(ConnectionState.done, null, null,
> null)

Comment: I have spent few hours to debug the code still unable to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign **getInventory**() to variable in **initstate**

```
var data;
 initState() {
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    data = getInventory();
    super.initState();
  }
```

And then use **StreamBuilder** instead  of future

```
Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<InventoryListData>(
              stream: data.asStream()!=null?data.asStream():getInventory().asStream(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                Log.e('VECHILE hasData', 'LOG-------:::${snapshot}');
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return buildList(snapshot);
                } else if(snapshot.hasError)  {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                    snapshot.error.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'regular',
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  )));
                }
                return progressBar();
              },
            ),
```

Comment: I was doing already but it didn't work, check my updated code

Comment: it will work fine if your getinventory method works perfectly.

Comment: Also, you should update your question with an error you are facing?

Comment: no error even debugging code. and i updated my code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you call `getInventory()` it's creating a new `Future`, so with every rebuild you start fetching again.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for the `FutureBuilder` class:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried calling inside `init` method and by accessing `future` variable , still null. and i have updated my code.